# Highlighting words with angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to allow the user to click on a word in a particular div and that word will be highlighted.  I am very new and **know** that what I have made is not close to working, but I have watched lots of videos and read lots of articles and am stuck.  Even if I don't get an answer of exactly what to do, any direction for my next step would be incredibly helpful.

I think I need a directive that would take the div, divide up the text and add a span around each word.  This div needs a click event that highlights the word. I have gone through lots of iterations and I am getting blocked at every point.

I have plenty of other angular built in directives working on the page, so I know that I have the app in general set up correctly, and I am including the directive in the app module.

```
<div my-prepare-text ng-bind-html="item.text | unsafe"></div>

angular.module('MyDirectives', [])
  .directive('myPrepareText', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element) {
    var words = element.text().split(' ');
    var text = words.join("</span> <span my-highlight ng-click='highlight()'>");
    element.html("<p><span my-highlight ng-click='highlight()'>" + text + "</span></p>");
  };
};
  })
```

Comment: pretty hard to do this without using the `Selection` API  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection and delgated events. Find a script that already does this in the dom...no point re-inventing the wheel

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a directive that gets the words as an attribute and then uses ng-repeat to create the spans.

I made an [basic example](http://jsbin.com/xeyoqunova/edit?html,css,js,console,output) to show this behavior.

```js
angular.module('MyDirectives', [])
  .directive('myPrepareText', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<div><span ng-repeat="word in words" class="single-word" ng-click="highlight($event)">{{word}}</span></div>',
      link: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.words = $element.attr('words').split(' ');
        $scope.highlight = function(event) {
          angular.element(event.target).toggleClass('highlight');
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.single-word::after {
  content: ' ';
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyDirectives">
  <div words="so many words to highlight" my-prepare-text></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that your approach fails because **angular won't compile what you insert as html in a directive via** `element.html(...)`.

Here's 2 solutions:

1. Use a template in the directive, instead of inserting html string. In the template, use `ng-repeat` to iterate over the array you split in the link function and let `ng-repeat` generate your `<span>`s.
2. Use the `$compile` service. I have found an easy example of how to use `$compile` [here](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angular-compile-how-it-works-how-to-use.html).

Keep in mind that angular always has to go through the 2 phases *compile* and *link* to make it's "directive magic" happen. It won't know that you have inserted a new directive via `element.html(...)` that it has to somehow process, unless you tell it so. This is *good* because otherwise the digest process would be unbearably slow, as angular would have to recursively check what happens to each DOM-element in every digest cycle.

I hope this got you closer to understand what angular is doing under the hood.